# changing .format length in python 3

Tags: python, format

I want to change the length of the formatting in my code,

```
symbolWanted = input('Input symbol wanted for triangle: ')
baseLength = int(input('Input base length of triangle(odd number): '))
for i in range (1,baseLength,2):
   print(('{:^100}').format(i*symbolWanted))
```

is there a way to change the length of the format using a variable e.g.

```
print(('{:^baseLength}').format(i*symbolWanted))
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use variables in format strings:

```
print(('{:^{bl}}').format(i*symbolWanted, bl=baseLength))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the advantage of Py >=3.6 with [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/):

```
print(f"{i * symbolWanted:^{baseLength}}")
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using   print((':^{baseLength}').format()

Comment: Format is not a method of `print`. This will raise an error.